# How to use put method to update a database from a form

Tags: database, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to update a database from a form without using any php, I'm using angularjs with MySql

If I use the following with the put method I can insert a user into the data base, I've

```
http://localhost:8080/CyberSolution/rest/user/register?u=tester&pw=fred&fname=Fred&lname=Smith&email=fred@localhost.com
```

I've made a basic html form

```
<form method="POST" action="">

  Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /><br />

  Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" /><br />
  email: <input type="text" name="email" size="15" /><br />
  First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lirst_name" size="15" /><br />
    <p><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /></p>

</form>
```

I'm working with AJS for the first time and also REST for the first time, I'm unsure on how to link the form to the database to update. I'm unsure what needs to go in the controllers.js as well

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use the $http service.

First use `ng-model` to store fields value in an object :

```
<form ng-submit="send_form()" action="">

  Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" ng-model="form.username" /><br />

  Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" ng-model="form.password"/><br />
  email: <input type="text" name="email" size="15" ng-model="form.email"/><br />
  First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" ng-model="form.first_name"/><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lirst_name" size="15" ng-model="form.last_name"/><br />
    <p><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /></p>

</form>
```

And then use in your controller (or even better, through a service) :

```
function myController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.send_form = function () {
       $http.put('http://localhost:8080/CyberSolution/rest/user/register', $scope.form).success(successCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to read up on ng-model a bit more this will really help me.

Comment: Leaving `action=""` like this might break the `ng-submit` in some web browsers -- Even tho it's empty, it might still submit the form via `GET`.